# Empty form when uploading a PDF file with XHR

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I've got a function to get a file type input, and upload the selected file using xhr, the problem it's working fine with images, but once I'm trying to upload a pdf file
the js function

```
function uploadFile() {
const files = document.getElementById("file").files;

if(files.length > 0 ){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    formData.append('__csrf', document.getElementById('csrf_profile').value);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Set POST method and ajax file path
    xhr.open("POST", "/api/user/background", true);

    // call on request changes state
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if(response.status === true){
                document.getElementById('message').innerText = 'cover image has been updated';
                document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'var(--main-colo)';
                reloadPage();
            }else{
                document.getElementById('message').innerText = response.message;
                document.getElementById('message').style.color = '#F00';
            }
        }
    };

    // Send request with data
    xhr.send(formData);

}else{
    document.getElementById('message').innerText = "Please select a file";
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = '#F00';
}
}
```

in my PHP handler I'm debugging using

```
die(print_r($_POST,true));
```

if it's an image I get `Array ( [__csrf] => token )` if it's a pdf I get `Array ( )` this is what I couldn't understand what exactly am I doing wrong here

Comment: It should be `formData.append("file", files.files[0]);`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller it didn't fix the problem

Comment: If you're uploading a file it will appear in $_FILES in PHP, not in $_POST. There are many many tutorials and past questions about this topic, and PHP has a documentation page specifically about file uploads too.

Comment: @ADyson I'm not trying to access the file here, I'm trying to do a first check of CSRF, before I move to the file, I just simply want even when I'm uploading a pdf file to find ``Array ( [__csrf] => token )``